# Blogger "read more" not showing

Tags: html, blogger

I have this problem. When I insert jump break into my post, it doesn't show "read more" option, it just shortens the article but without making the hyperlink visible and clickable.

[image]

I have to insert it manually- "Viac" means "read more" but the problem is that it doesn't disappear after clicking on it as it should when it is the original "read more" function.

Im desperate, I googled it everywhere nothing works:( Do you know what should I do with it?

THE CODE:

```
 <data:post.title/>
                  </b:if>
                <b:else/>
                  <data:post.title/>
                </b:if>
              </b:if>
            </h3>
          </b:if>

          <div class='post-header'>
            <div class='post-header-line-1'/>
          </div>

          <div class='post-body entry-content' expr:id='&quot;post-body-&quot; + data:post.id'>
            <data:post.body/>
            <div style='clear: both;'/> <!-- clear for photos floats -->
          </div>
         <div class='jump-link'>
<a expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#more&quot;' expr:title='data:post.title'>Continue Reading...</a>
</div>
          <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>

    <img class='thumb' expr:src='data:post.firstImageUrl'/>

<data:post.snippet/> <a class='jumplink' expr:href='data:post.url'>Pokračovať v čítaní</a>

    <b:else/>

    <data:post.body/>
```

Thank you very much for your advices in advance!

Comment: You can always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65765554/edit) your question if you want, no need to fix typos in the comments.

Comment: Do you have the code for it? It is hard to find a solution to your answer when there is no legitimate problem described with the code. Include your code, and specify where you are running in the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I put the code in the description, I have problem with this part:
<a expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#more&quot;' expr:title='data:post.title'>Continue Reading...</a>
</div>
          <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>

    <img class='thumb' expr:src='data:post.firstImageUrl'/>

<data:post.snippet/> <a class='jumplink' expr:href='data:post.url'>Pokračovať v čítaní</a>